# What is the correct way to use Laravel basic auth with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, laravel

Here is the approach that I follow.

I secure the routes for my API like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '/api/v1'), function () {

    Route::get('dashboard', array('before' => 'basic.once', function () {
        return 'Dashboard';
    }));

});
```

I am planning to use basic auth over an SSL connection.

I have to send username and password to the with every request.

I understand that I need to store some user details on the client side (angular/browser) so that the user logs in once and is allowed to access protected routes until his session is valid.

What I don't understand is what user information do I store at the client end and how?

The API will be used for building mobile apps in future.

What is the simplest thing I can do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is that when a user register (or you create a user), you add an extra field not just the standard credentials (username, password), this extra field can be token what you'll generate when you create the user, after that when your user logs in you send back to him this unique token, and at client side (angularJS) you can store this token for example in session storage, and after this you need to send this token with every API call. To simplify the back-end you can make a filter to test the token and log in the user. This will be important if you want to use your application on mobile devices where aren't cookies, so you will log in the users with every call.